# Drawing Video Frames in OpenGL on Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm currently working on a system which displays video frames (as bitmaps) via OpenGL ES 1.0 on Android. My issue is that I have not been able to get more than about 10 fps.

After doing some testing, I've determined that one of the biggest bottlenecks is the need for the bitmap to have its width and height both be a power of 2. A 640x480 video has to be scaled up to 1024x1024, for example. Without the scaling, I've been able to get about 40-50fps, but the texture just appears white, which does me no good.

I know that OpenGL ES 2.0 supports using non-power of two textures, but I have no experience with shaders / anything else new in 2.0

Is there any way I can get around this issue? How do other video plays get such good performance in comparison to what I have? I have included some code for reference.

```
private Bitmap makePowerOfTwo(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    // If one of the bitmap's resolutions is not a power of two
    if(!isPowerOfTwo(bitmap.getWidth()) || !isPowerOfTwo(bitmap.getHeight()))
    {
        int newWidth = nextPowerOfTwo(bitmap.getWidth());
        int newHeight = nextPowerOfTwo(bitmap.getHeight());

        // Generate a new bitmap which has the needed padding
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
    }
    else
    {
        return bitmap;
    }
}

private static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int num)
{
    // Check if a bitwise and of the number and itself minus one is zero
    return (num & (num - 1)) == 0;
}

private static int nextPowerOfTwo(int num)
{
    if(num <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int nextPowerOfTwo = 1;

    while(nextPowerOfTwo < num)
    {
        nextPowerOfTwo <<= 1; // Bitwise shift left one bit
    }

    return nextPowerOfTwo;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because a texture has to be a power of two, doesn't mean that your data has to be a power of two.

You're free to create a 1024x1024 (or 1024x512) texture during initialization with `glTexImage`, fill in the lower 640x480 with your bitmap data with `glTexSubImage`, and then display the lower 640x480 of the texture with some intelligent texcoords `(0,0) to (640/1024, 480/1024)`. The remainder of the texture will just contain empty space that's never seen.

Comment: I'd add some reference specifically to glTexSubimage, since it's possible the OP is also using glTexImage() on every frame (which has other negative performance implications even if you're updating the entire image).

Comment: What downsides are there to calling glTexImage() each frame as opposed to glTexSubimage()? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe glTexImage will alloc a new memory region in VRAM, and then discard the old data. glTexSubImage just overwrites the bytes in the existing memory, so no memory has to be allocated/deallocated. @Samusaaron3

Comment: Can you explain this further, because i can't understand it. First we create Bitmap 1024*1024, we use texImage2D() to tiw it as a backgroung, and then we, when we want just put another image (that is not power of two) with a texSubImage2D? Is this correct? Can you put some code here?